# Autoupdate Jtable from JPanel to Jframe eclipse

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I Have Database JTable From my JPanel class and i want to use it on my JFRame Class

And I want My JTable AutoUpdate  by Clicking some Buttons
Its not error but it dont want to AutoUpdate unless i put Jframe on Jpanel Class Which will make a new Frame

heres My JPanel

```
 public class TUsers extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

    String [] header = {"Id","name","address"};
    JTable BTab = new JTable(); 
    JScrollPane scrPnl = new JScrollPane();
    public Object [][] table = null;

     TUsers(){
        Dbcon dc = new Dbcon();
        Connection psql = dc.getConnection();
        try 
        {
            Statement stmt = psql.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM public.patrons ORDER BY id ASC";
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData meta = res.getMetaData();
            int y  = meta.getColumnCount();
            int x = 0;
            while(res.next())
            {
                y = res.getRow();
            }
            table = new Object[x][y];
            int n = 0;
            res.beforeFirst();
            while(res.next())
            {
                table[n][0]=res.getString("Id");
                table[n][1]=res.getString("name");
                table[n][2]=res.getString("address");
                x++;
            }
            scrPnl.setViewportView(BTab);
            BTab.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(table, header));
            TableColumnModel table = BTab.getColumnModel();

            table.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(2);
            table.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
            table.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(180);

            scrPnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 120));

            add(scrPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            stmt.close();
            res.close();
```

heres from my JFrame  Class

```
  public class AddUser extends JFrame {
    TUsers t = new TUsers();


AddUser()
{
    setTitle("Admin");
    setLocation(400,400);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

}

    void Layout()
  {
   getContentPane().add(t).setBounds(10, 225, 350, 150);
   //if i delete this it wont show the table

    setVisible(true);
  } 



    void EventHandle() 
   {
  b_crt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Dbcon dc = new Dbcon();
            Connection psql = dc.getConnection();
            try
            {
                Statement stmt = psql.createStatement();
                String sql = "INSERT INTO public.patrons VALUES ('"
                            +t_id.getText()+"','"
                            +t_usrnm.getText()+"','"
                            +t_adrs.getText()+"');";
                int i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                if(i == i) 
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                }
                Clear();
            }
            catch(Exception x)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.getMessage());
            }

            TUsers t = new TUsers();

         }
        });
   }
}
```

i already put
repaint() and revalidate() on my JPanel But It doesnt work

Comment: You need to reload the `TableModel` when ever you think the data has been changed in the database

Comment: i call the Table class on my Create ActionListener
but it dont change the table on my JFrame  Unless i Reopen it

Comment: Why should it?  You're creating a new instance of the class, which is not displayed on the screen, or has any relationship to anything actually displayed on the screen

Comment: so i have to reload the `TableModel` in my ActionListener?  
t.fireTableDataChanged();?

Comment: No, the table data hasn’t changed, the database has, you need to pull the results from the database again and update the table model

Comment: do i have to make a new constructor in my JFrame to doing that eventough its the same habit as my TUsers on my JPanel? im srry i just dont understand how to display it on another class

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's take a step back and have a rethink of your `TUsers` class.

The current implementation has a side effect of loading the database information as part of the classes initialisation phase.  There are a couple of issues with this, the primary issue is the fact that you can't update the table without creating a new instance.

A better approach may be to simply build the basic UI in the constructor and then providing a separate "load" method which re-loads the data from the database, maybe something like...

```
public class TUsers extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String[] header = {"Id", "name", "address"};
    JTable BTab = new JTable();
    JScrollPane scrPnl = new JScrollPane();

    TUsers() {
        // Build the UI
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(header, 0);
        BTab = new JTable(model);
        scrPnl.setViewportView(BTab);
        add(scrPnl);
    }

    public void loadData() throws SQLException {
        Dbcon dc = new Dbcon();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM public.patrons ORDER BY id ASC";
        try (Connection psql = dc.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = psql.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(header, 0);
            while (res.next()) {
                String[] rowData = new String[3];
                rowData[0] = res.getString("Id");
                rowData[1] = res.getString("name");
                rowData[2] = res.getString("address");
                model.addRow(rowData);
            }
            BTab.setModel(model);
            BTab.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(2);
            BTab.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
            BTab.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(180);
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure you call `loadData` at some point, otherwise it will show an empty table.

Now, when you want to, you can call `loadData` and have the table refreshed...

```
public class AddUser extends JFrame {

    TUsers t = new TUsers();

    AddUser() {
        setTitle("Admin");
        setLocation(400, 400);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // When does t get added??
    }

    void Layout() {
        getContentPane().add(t).setBounds(10, 225, 350, 150);
        //if i delete this it wont show the table
        // This is a symptom of a different problem
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void EventHandle() {
        b_crt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Dbcon dc = new Dbcon();
                String sql = "INSERT INTO public.patrons VALUES ('"
                        + t_id.getText() + "','"
                        + t_usrnm.getText() + "','"
                        + t_adrs.getText() + "');";
                try (Connection psql = dc.getConnection();
                        Statement stmt = psql.createStatement()) {
                    int i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                    if (i == i) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                    }
                    t.loadData();
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And while I have your attention, let me introduce you to a couple of little friends...

## `PreapredStatement`

`PreparedStatement` protects you from possible SQL injection issues and supports a number of different data types, saving your from having to try and figure out how to convert them for different databases

See [How to use `PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

```
void EventHandle() {
    b_crt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Dbcon dc = new Dbcon();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO public.patrons VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            try (Connection psql = dc.getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement stmt = psql.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                stmt.setString(1, t_id.getText());
                stmt.setString(2, t_usrnm.getText());
                stmt.setString(3, t_adrs.getText());
                int i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                if (i == i) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                }
                t.loadData();
            } catch (Exception x) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
}
```

## try-with-resources

Resource management is a very important task and which can be complicated. You code risks leaving resources open if any one of many operations fail.  A better solution is to make use the available "auto closing" support

You'll see it in the above code, but you can also read [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)